# How to go (in a random order) through all the elements of a 2D array with a specific state

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a simple 2D array in C++ like this:

```
Cell field[57][57];
enum State {foo, bar, baz};
```

Where each `Cell` is defined as

```
typedef struct Cell_t{
    enum State state;
    int value;
    float temperature;
}Cell;
```

My goal is to go through the `field` and do something with all the cells which have their `state` currently set as `foo`. The goal is to go through these in a random order. After having gone through all of the `foo` cells, one time step is finished and the next can happen.

That means that for example, the field might contain 1000 cells whose state is `baz`, and 197 cells whose state is `foo`, the rest is `bar`. They are all at random places in the 2D array. I need to go through all the `foo` cells in **random** order, do something with them, and *only* them.

The thing is that the actions of one `foo` cell can turn a cell that was not `foo` before into a `foo` cell. This new cell, however, will not make its move in this step, only the `foo` cells that were `foo` before the first change of this step can make their move. What would be the correct way to do this?

What I tried:

I went through the field sequentially, looking for `foo` cells, added their coordinates to a vector of coordinate arrays `{x,y}`, then chose one randomly, accessed it (by knowing its coordinates) in the field, did the necessary action, then deleted the coordinates from the vector. Then I chose the next random coordinates, and the next, until the vector is empty. The next step can begin afterwards.

However, I can have thousands upon thousands of cells at any given time and constantly adding and removing items from the vector can be costly. What is the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all the coordinates of foo cells in an `std::vector` and `std::shuffle` it. That's what I would do:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  Cell field[57][57];

  std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> cellsToVisit;
  for (int i = 0; i < 57; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 57; j++) {
      if (field[i][j].state == foo) {
        cellsToVisit.push_back({i, j});
      }
    }
  }
  std::default_random_engine rng;
  std::shuffle(cellsToVisit.begin(), cellsToVisit.end(), rng);
  for (const auto& ij: cellsToVisit) {
    std::cout << "Visit cell " << ij.first << ", " << ij.second << std::endl;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I used this solution